# Fullscreen iframe on mobile

Tags: html, css, iframe, mobile, responsive

I'm trying to implement a full screen iframe video from Youtube.
It works perfect on the web and tablet, but on the mobile the video it keeps the aspect ratio which is not really what I want.

I would want to get rid of the black margins from top and bottom if that is possible.
That's how is looking now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQFTl.png

Answer (score 0):

It won't go unless you rotate the screen. Or you can use it like this.

```css
.video {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
}
.video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```